# Permission denied error while creating database through java in hive

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, bigdata

I have tried to create database in hive using java.

But I got this error while running the code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while
>   processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got
>   exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException
>   Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/hive/warehouse/sampledb.db":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

I have given read an write privileges to the folder `/user/hive/warehouse/`. Still I am getting this error. Any remedies???

Comment: Only `root` user has write permission to hdfs directory `/user/hive/warehouse/sampledb.db` . Which user you are using to execute the java code?

Comment: But you exception telling you are using different user `Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE, `. You are trying with `hive` user. Are you on root user or you are using `sudo java` to run the java program?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am executing the java code as root, but internally the query is being executed by hive as 'hive' user. Lost on this.

Comment: Thank you for your responses..